# Apache generating too many rotatelogs.exe on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-server-2003

I'm seeing some odd behavior with Apache's `rotatelogs.exe`.  On one of my servers I'm seeing multiple `rotatelogs.exe` counting into the 100's.  Normally I usually only see 6 which I can rationalize to the 3 logs I have rotating.  Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can prevent it from happening?  When the `rotatelogs.exe` processes get up into the 100's everything slows down and Apache is effectively shut down because it can't process requests anymore.

We are using the following line in our `httpd.conf` file:

> ErrorLog "|\"C:/Program Files/Apache2/bin/rotatelogs.exe\" \"C:/Program Files/Apache2/logs/error_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S\" 20M"

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this was a bug in the version of Apache we were using.  The RotateLogs processes were becoming unattached from the Apache instance and not shutting down properly.  By upgrading to the latest 2.0 branch of Apache (2.0.63 at the time of this writing) the problem was corrected.